# Why is my browserify task appending the end of an exports twice

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, gulp, browserify

I am having an issue with my browserify task.

For some reason my browserify task keeps appending the following to the end and I can't see why

```
, format);
        };
    });
    },{}]},{},[1])
```

this is the Task:

```
gulp.task('browserify', function() {
        return browserify(sourceFile, {debug:true})
            .bundle()
            .pipe(source(destFile))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(destFolder));
    });
```

and This is the result:

```
12:[function(require,module,exports){
'use strict';

module.exports = (function ($filter){
    return function(input, format){
        return $filter('date')(new Date(input *1000), format);
    };
});
},{}]},{},[1])), format);
    };
});
},{}]},{},[1])
```

But my watchify task works fine. This is the task

```
gulp.task('watch-browserify', function() {
        var bundler = watchify(sourceFile, {debug:true});
        bundler.on('update', rebundle);

        function rebundle() {
            return bundler.bundle()
                .pipe(source(destFile))
                .pipe(gulp.dest(destFolder));
        }

        return rebundle();
    });
```

And this is the result:

```
12:[function(require,module,exports){
'use strict';

module.exports = (function ($filter){
    return function(input, format){
        return $filter('date')(new Date(input *1000), format);
    };
});

},{}]},{},[1])
```

Even if I remove the file contents of the file I still get

```
},{}]},{},[1])e,module,exports){

},{}]},{},[1])
```

Can help anyone can offer would be great

Comment: It works ok for me. What versions of browserify, gulp, and vinyl-source-stream? What platform? By the way, you don't need to wrap your exported function in parens.

Comment: Are you sure that only one file is matched by your `sourceFile` pattern? Isn't the issue coming from a file wrongly bunded?

Comment: @JMM Thanks it appears it was an issue with the version of browserify I was using, I had the latest version installed (7.1) but watchify a different version (3.46.1) hence why that worked, so I changed the version to 3.46.1 and it solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears it was an issue with the version of browserify I was using, I had version installed (7.1) but watchify a different version (3.46.1) hence why that worked, so I changed the version to 3.46.1 and it solved the problem. I did try with the latest version (8.0.3) but had the same issue so sticking with 3.46.1 for now